# I can't see my weapons! What's going on?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Anyone ever have the issue of their weapons disappearing?

Comment: i get it very often on a round start, just double swap fix it for me most of the time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to clear up HUD issues such as radars being stuck, weapons not showing, killfeed stuck, etc., the easiest way to do so is to refresh the HUD by creating a demo, then stopping it.

By running the command below in the developer console:

```
record DEMO_NAME_GOES_HERE; stop;
```

You are forcing the game to record a demo, forcing it to refresh and redraw HUD elements.  Unless you specify the game to stop recording right away, it will continue to record whatever you are playing and will take up memory.

The name of the demo can be anything you want, so you could simply say `record a; stop;`, and that would be sufficient enough to redraw the HUD.

Alternatively, from my own experience, switching weapons to another weapon, then back to the "missing" weapon will fix the issue most of the time.  This solution is much more preferred as creating a demo and stopping it will freeze the game for a short period of time.

Comment: I knew about the record part, I just forgot that you can do the stop; afterwards.

Comment: Is the record feature similar to the replay system in TF2?

Comment: @ShadowZ. both run on Source, so yes. Albeit, CS:GO runs on a different version of Source compared to TF2

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who has played CS:S and CS:GO has dealt with invisible weapons. (Not entirely sure about CS 1.6). We all think it is the worst thing ever, cause we can't sometimes see that sexy skin we got. Well, truth be told, there is an easy fix for it.

Before you do any of this, you will need to know how to enable and open Developer Console.

Follow these instructions:

1. Press esc
2. Go to Options
3. Go to Keyboard
4. Click Advanced
5. Click "Enable Developer Console"
6. And then press 'esc' until you get back into the game. From there, press the tilde key, or (~)

Now all you have to do, is open up console, and type in the following command:

```
record 1
```

Now after you type this, you will have a recorded dem file in your csgo folder, so if you want, you can go and delete it.

If I have confused anyone, please let me know, and I will try to make it more clear.

Comment: So a gameplay Record fix it? Never heard about this kind of fix

Comment: I think you have your order of operations mixed up; you should be listing how to get to the developer console first.